# How can I detect if any key pressed on my win form application?

Tags: c#, multithreading, combobox, keypress

The form keyPress event is working ok this way:

```
  private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.KeyChar >= 30 && e.KeyChar <= 127) || (e.KeyChar >= 10 && e.KeyChar <= 31))
            {
                //do something
                MessageBox.Show("asdasd");
            }
        }
```

But if I started a thread which is updating for example a combobox text, the KeyPress event is not working at all!

```
public void startcbadd()
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
            {
                comboBox1.Text = "test";
            }));

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t = new Thread(startcbadd);
            t.Start();
        }
```

Do you have any idea to sovle it?

Comment: Are you assuming that setting the `Text` of a control will raise a `KeyPress` event?  Why would it, when no key was pressed?

Comment: You are doing the computer equivalent of expecting someone to pick up the phone because the door bell went.

Comment: No, my problem that if there are any text filed like textbox or combobox in the form, there is no appearing messagebox with (asdasd). without any textfield, if i press any key the messagebox appearing

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are doing, but I guess those controls handle the KeyPress event on their own and don't bubble through to their parent. But that has nothing to do with your second snippet. It's completely unrelated to your question, imho.

Comment: But, It is not the best way for me because there are a lot of textboxes, comboboxes, buttons etc..

Comment: It seems that this solved the problem:  Form1.KeyPreview=true;

Comment: Even better, yes. You should write your own answer so this can be useful for future users.